# Google Spreadsheets: how to generate a report for the most commonly used words

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, report

I have a google spreadsheet, I use to log programs that occur in my work everyday, I have a column, I use to register the names of each individual issue.

What I want is to somehow generate a report or a statistic, that would tell me that top 4 or 5 issues during a specific day.

For example, I use column **B** to log issues names, and issues names for that day, let's say (error1, error2, error3, error4, error5, error6, error7), and for example the most common issues(based on how many times, those words are used, throughout column B), for today, are error1, error2, error6, error7.

What I want is to highlight B1 to B200 for instance and generate a report or some sort of statistic, or even a specific equation, that would produce, the most common 4 or 5 issues(error1, error2, error6, error7) that are being repeated though the highlighted portion.

Thank you for taking the time in reading my question.

I hope that make sense, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using pivot table? put column B in row headers and also put it values to count them, then just filter for the top 5 values (you can do this exact filtering in excel, I'm not sure how it works in google).

Answer (score 0):

If the same issue is always written identically you can write in a column the different issues let us say D and in the second column E use 
Countif($B$1:$B$200,D1) and drag it down

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, however, what I mean is, that I want some how, when I enter an equation or use a certain add on, it produce the 5 most common used words (issue names), that I can submit an accurate daily report of the most common issue.                                                                                                         keeping in mind, that they're all whiten identically.

Comment: For example issue names through out a day(error1, error2 , error3, error4, error5, error1, error2 , error1, erro2 , error5 , error1) what I would need at the end of the day, to use a tool or an equation, to produce the top 5 used words, through out a specific column range, from error1 to error5. I hope that make sense.